# Excel does not calculate formula automatically, that is inserted via VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a formula via vba and `.FormulaR1C1` but Excel does not seem to realize it is a formula. It shows the correct formula within the formula bar and a Reference Error in the cell itself.

I tried a test sheet with a simple formula

```
    .Cells(i, recalcCol).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC(-1)"
```

The cell format is set at general. Inserting `.NumberFormat = "general"` at any point before or after does not change the behavior. It is definitely not a text cell.

I can enter the cell with double-click or `F2` and then hit `Enter` and Excel removes the error and displays the correct result. But doing that for all changed cells is not possible.

I also tried recalculating the sheet, but no change there either.

Any hints?

Thx Kaz

Comment: `"=RC[-1]"` square brackets

Comment: Damn ... that easy ... thats what happens when translating from german to english formulas. Thx a lot! You want the correct answer vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `=RC[-1]` is the correct formula.

However, in order to see the formula in RC format yourself, do the following:

- Select the cell with the formula
- Run the code below
- Check the immediate window

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print Selection.FormulaR1C1
    Debug.Print Selection.Formula
    Debug.Print Selection.FormulaLocal

End Sub
```

Concerning German to English, while you are using `.FormulaR1C1` or `.Formula` you should not worry about it, Excel takes care of it. You should be worried only if you pass the formula as a string through `.FormulaLocal`.

---

This is the result in the immediate window from the `Sub` above, using a simple SUM() formula:

```
=RC[-1]+SUM(5,5)
=M10+SUM(5,5)
=M10+SUMME(5;5)
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the FormulaLocal part. I have always ignored that, on the grounds of just putting in the correct formula myself. But have never thought about using it to get the translation.